# How to move image/div markup center of the div containing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having a markup like this

```
<p>
    <img hspace="4" alt="" src="sampleimage.png">

    Many in her village believed that girls should not be educated, and someone burned down the coffee trees on Enatha’s family farm – their only source of income – to discourage her from continuing with her studies.&nbsp;However, Enatha’s parents continued to support her education, and in 2011, she earned a spot at the Gashora Girls’ Academy of Science and Technology.

</p>
```

I have added text-wrap-around-image effect by adding float-right to the image. Currently text wrap around the image, but the image is at the top.

**Current Snapshot** [image]

I want the image to be in the middle (among) the text say 2 lines below the text. Is there anyway to achieve something like this

**Expected Behaviour**
[image]

Comment: try to use `float: right; position: absolute; top: 50%;`

Comment: I think that you"ll have to split the <p>   http://jsfiddle.net/383mbtnc/2/

This is the far as I got

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is by placing the image inside the paragraph. However the exact position will depend on how the text before the image wraps and that can depend on many factors outside your control (e.g. text size, font, available width and most importantly the tiny font rendering differences between browsers and operating systems).

```
<p>

    Many in her village believed that girls should not be educated, and someone burned down the coffee trees on Enatha’s family farm – their only source of income – to discourage her from continuing with her studies.&nbsp;

    <img hspace="4" alt="" src="sampleimage.png">

    However, Enatha’s parents continued to support her education, and in 2011, she earned a spot at the Gashora Girls’ Academy of Science and Technology.

</p>
```

Comment: I dont have any control in editing the HTML markups. But i can play with javascript to do something like this. Gotto to think though